# zsh - prompt is typing control character

Tags: unix, terminal, zsh

I am using the zsh shell on my mac.

However my when I type `Ctrl-A` and `Ctrl-E` I am getting the characters on the screen instead of moving to beginning or the end of the line.

`ps -ef ^A^E^A^E`

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nvm found a solution, it was a problem with my keybindings.

I was using preztro and set the editor binding to vim whereas it was set to emacs in zsh